# What will happen if .space is exceeded in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm new to assembly programming and trying to learn by following someone else's code. So the question arose, What will happen if we exceed space reserved by .space? Will MARS 4.5 allocate additional space for us during run time or we will overwrite bytes after those reserved?

```
.data
input:  .space 4
.text
li $v0, 8
li $a1, 6 #intentionally, allows to read more than 4 bytes.
la $a0, input
syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

In a real program, usually your code would be linked with other code that also put stuff in `.data`, so `input+4` would be the location of some other label+reserved space.

If not, the memory mapping that `.data` is in might be a whole number of virtual-memory pages, so there's effectively unused padding until a multiple of 4096 bytes.  (But that only applies on systems using virtual memory; otherwise some other section could start right after; check the addresses of other symbols after linking)

On MARS specifically, see settings->memory configuration to see exactly where each section starts in the memory map.